# Accessing your account being anonymous

Tags: android, forms, android-studio, anonymous-function

I am developing anonymous app. Basically user can fill out form. That form data can be viewed by anyone who were using the app. Think about I fill out form saying that "rabbit located in Australia."

Then another user browsing these data from browsing activity. He can view "Rabbit located in Australia' but he cannot be able to see who submitted form.

Now for Is there any mechanisam that allows me to fill out as many forms as I can and still can access my all forms without registering myself to the app.

Think about Instagram -- posting photos without Signing up to Instagram. The person who posted photo can re edit and see all their photos. First I thought of using Mac Address but if user changed phone then all the forms will be gone.

Comment: So, you need a way to uniquely identify an anonymous user? Because, that's the opposite of what _anonymous_ means

Comment: Yes however I don't wanna grab any of their personal details. @JChrist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of phones local storage , like a key which is attached to the form which user fills and the same key is stored in user's phones local storage.
While giving editing option just check whether the key matches if yes then that's the original user.

Comment: Yes But If someone else want to browse the form or whatever he wrote they cant because it is stored on local storage rather than cloud @sanky

Comment: Sorry you are getting me wrong,
I said store only the key in the local storage not the content.
the key will act as an identifier to the content and its author
eg. content A - author Sanky - key "55345"
now here key goes to the local storage of sanky as well as the hidden field (or data not visible in form) to the cloud

Comment: What if person changed phone ?? @sanky

Comment: So you want all these measures then do one thing just keep a simple social login like fb or google
and don't print the name with form as who filled it (this is what being anonymous is ) like quora does .

Comment: The application main goal is to be anonymous. So if i launch it in commerical market. After seeing login page, users will think the app is not anonymous